# C#: non-flag enum, is there any easier way for checking enum to match one of multiple values?

Tags: c#, enums

Here is the sample, `CommandType` is an enum. It's a none flag enum.

```
CommandType cmdType = CommandType.back;
if (cmdType == CommandType.back || cmdType == CommandType.forward || cmdType == CommandType.previous || cmdType == CommandType.home)
{
//do something
}
```

Is there any way to simplify the "if" statement?

Comment: If you don't want flags probably you want extension method

Comment: No. Continue using the `if` and go to a new line just before or just after each `||`. At least it will become a little more readable.

Comment: `FlagAttribute` makes different `.ToString` output, you can still use `.HasFlag` method on enums without this attribute.

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by simplify. You can do something like `new[] {CommandType.back, CommandType.forward, CommandType.previous, CommandType.home}.Contains(cmdType)`, but is that "more simple"? Doubt that.

Answer (score 3):

How about a `switch` ?

```
switch(cmdType)
{
    case CommandType.back:
    case CommandType.forward:
    case CommandType.previous:
    case CommandType.home:
       // do something 
       break;
}
```

Comment: While it is more "beautiful" (but I do think that especially in this case, *Beauty is in the eye of the beholder*), not sure if it is shorter... Remember the final break! :-)

Comment: argh! one minute too late ;)

Comment: @InBetween It was the fact that you added the `break` and the `default`  :-) Perfection was beaten by "just good enough" :-)

Comment: Don't worry @InBetween, we now have another answer 2 minutes late :)

Comment: Well I think it wouldn't compile @SelmanGenç

Comment: yep, correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a switch statement. It performs better and can be more readable:

```
switch (cmdType)
{
    case CommandType.back:
    case CommandType.forward:
    case CommandType.previous:
    case CommandType.home:
        //do somehting
        break;
    default:
        //do something else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement

```
CommandType cmdType = CommandType.home;

switch(cmdType)
{
    case CommandType.back:
    case CommandType.forward:
    case CommandType.previous:
    case CommandType.home:
        // do somethinig
        break;
}
```